# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, electron, desktop-application

I build my app using electron and these errors occurred in chrome console. Otherwise my app is working fine if I run it through ng serve. Errors are as follows:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
polyfills.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
styles.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
vendor.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/C:/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

My index.html file in dist folder is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IMS</title>
   <base href="/"> 

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="styles.50e334ed602d9817f7d7.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>

 <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.9c6676de3e2948b5be6b.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.e19c18e1070c8c3aa743.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.e2a9b8f51e6c245f32be.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.eb7ca8d005a358b399e4.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

and code of my index.html file in src folder is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IMS</title>
   <base href="./"> 

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

 <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> Add the base element just after the `<head>` tag. If the `app` folder is the application root, as it is for our application, set the `href` value *exactly* as shown here.

The `<base href="/">` tells the Angular router what is the static part of the URL. The router then only modifies the remaining part of the URL.
Set your Base href to '/' in your `src/index.html`

```
<base href="/">
```

You can learn more about base href [here](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/06/angular-4-use-of-base-href-and-deploy-url-build-options/)

Comment: this didn't worked for me, app works fine with ng serve command. but when i build for electron it didn't load files because files are loaded from dist folder after build.

Comment: I set it to `<base href="./">` which worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked fine both for `ng serve` and `ng build`:

```
<base href="">
```